# Story about a girl whose mother has a marsupial pouch

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about a strange little girl whose mother has a marsupial pouch in which the girl's father takes refuge. Older science fiction.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take a look at our [tour] and [help] to get a feel for the site. You may also want to check out [Tips for asking Story Identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/57310) to give our expert finders the best chance at helping you.

Comment: This question could be improved by being more specific with the phrase "Older science fiction." What year did you read it, and what decade(s) did you get the impression it was from?

Answer (score 16):

This is likely "[Nada](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58787)" (1964) by Thomas M. Disch

Nada Perez is an apparently unintelligent, uninterested student in a class of special education students.  The teacher, Oveta Wohlmuth, suspects Nada of hidden intelligence, and tries to gain Nada's confidence.  Nada turns out to be able to paint superbly, but with a very short attention span, and great disdain for most of the great masters.

Oveta discusses Nada with a friend and colleague of hers, Mrs. Butler.  On day Oveta meets Nada's mother, Mrs. Perez, and is shocked to find her drinking heavily and also giving Nada alcohol.  They arrange for Nada to be taken be children's aid, and in searching her things find additional paintings Nada has done, including a spaceship arriving on Earth, and one labeled "Mommy and Daddy:"

> The woman was recognizably "Mrs. Perez."  Nada had captured perfectly the stuporous expression, the ponderous weight of the breasts and abdomen.  Of the man, only his face visible:  eyes twinkling an ageless wisdom and unwanted knowledge, an ironic smile on his thin lips. The rest of him—his dwarf's body—was nestled securely in Mrs. Perez's marsupial pouch.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.

Comment: @ThomasRyba You're welcome!  Please accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark in the upper-left of the answer (below the voting arrows).  That will help future searchers find it by prioritizing this result since it has a correct answer.